# Cannot save any products

Tags: magento2.2.2

I have done a basic product import (sku, name, etc) but now when I go to add more details to the product page and then click save I get this error.

[image: Error I Get]

I also keep getting this error randomly when clicking buttons, I can't personally work out a pattern to it. (2nd image is behind the pop-up box)

[image]
[image]

To get the error that time I pressed back on a product page, which replicates the issue each time but isn't the only time it happens.

The database is surely connected because I wouldn't be able to import products without it?

Anyway im at a loss and couldn't find anyone having the same issue as me online.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S some server info.

Ubuntu 16.04

PHP 7.0.22

MySQL 5.7.21

Another Update:

I have another instance of Magento 2.2.2 running on an i dentical server and it lets me save products fine.

Comment: clear your /var/log/system.log and again save product and show add your log to your question.

Comment: Sorry @Rizwan I tried disabling a module and it gave a white screen to admin panel and frontend. I then tried to restore from the backups and there was some kind of php error. As I had only really built the theme so far i just saved the theme an started again on a new server.